# Problems running puppeteer inside EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I am using AWS CloudFormation to deploy my application inside AWS. 
I'm using a `t2.2xlarge` EC2 instance inside an ECS Cluster with Load Balancing.

I have a microservice written in nodejs that process some HTML, converts it to PDF and upload the output to S3. That's where I use puppeteer.

The problem is that whenever I execute the application inside the ec2 instance, the code reaches a point in which it opens a new page and stops, not resolve, or never ends. Sincerely, I don't know what is happening.

This is part of the code snippet that it executes:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  args: [
    '--no-sandbox',
    '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
    '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
    '--disable-web-security'
  ]
});

console.log('Puppeteer before launch ...');
console.log(await browser.version());
console.log('Puppeteer launched ...');

const page = await browser.newPage();

console.log('Fetching contents ...');

const URL = `http://${FRONTEND_ENDPOINT}/Invoice/${invoiceData.id}`;
await page.goto(URL, {
  waitUntil: ['networkidle0']
});

await page.content();
const bodyHandle = await page.$('body');
await page.evaluate(body => body.innerHTML, bodyHandle);
await bodyHandle.dispose();

console.log('Saving pdf file ...');

await page.emulateMedia('screen');

await page.pdf({
  path: path.join(__dirname, '../tmp/page1.pdf'),
  format: 'A4',
  printBackground: true
});
await browser.close();
```

I am basically crawling a page, getting its HTML contents and converting it to PDF.

These are my logs:

1. Puppeteer before launch ...
2. Puppeteer launched ...

And it does not print anything else.

UPDATE:
This is the print of the logs using the *DEBUG* flag
[image]

Comment: Does your instance have enough RAM?

Comment: I have tried with the following instance types:
“t2.micro”,
“t2.small”,
“m4.large”,
“m4.2xlarge”,
“c4.large”,
“i2.xlarge”,
“i2.8xlarge”. I don't think it's RAM. I'm currently testing without running it inside a cluster to see if it works.

Comment: That makes sense. Could you try something extreme? Remove everything after the `Fetching contents` log, wrap both that line and the `newPage` line in a `try`/`catch`, and see if you catch any errors.

Comment: Of course, I have all wrapped inside a try/catch. That is the main problem, actually it does not trigger any error. It just stops logging. I ran it without a cluster and it worked perfectly. The problem is when I run it inside a cluster with an Application Load Balancer

Comment: That is really strange, and it sounds like the problem may be with the AWS side of things, but I don’t really know, unfortunately. Sorry I couldn’t be of more help!